# How to test/mock this static factory (used for graph construction)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

So, I have implemented my business classes, where I pass in all dependencies via the constructor, so I can mock those out and easily unit test them. This works great so far, but then, at one point, I need to create an object graph out of those objects. For this, I'm using a static factory (I can't use a DI framework, sadly). Example:

```
public class FooBar {
    public FooBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public class Foo  {
    public Foo() {}
}

public class Bar {
    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

public class GraphFactory {
    public static FooBar newFooBar() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar bar = new Bar(foo);

        return new FooBar(foo, bar);
    }
}
```

So, I'm not able to really test the GraphFactory (can't mock the dependencies), which is kinda ok (not much work is done here). But what if construction of the graph is more complex, i.e. it involves looking up some properties, doing JNDI lookups and so on?

Should I still not write a unit test for this? Is my class design maybe broken? Isn't the purpose of unit testing to test classes in isolation?

Comment: How about providing an example that compiles? I doubt `public static newFooBar(){...} ` actually compiles...

Comment: @Romain Sry, fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this design and it is fully testable. If we focus on the single responsibilty of the factory -- it is responsible for assembling the object graph -- the tests for this are straight forward:

1. Set up the factory with its prerequisites.
2. Invoke the factory method.
3. Assert that the object was constructed to your requirements: default values are set, etc.

In the example above, foo, bar, and foobar are the result of the test and do not need to be mocked.

If the assembly of the object graph is more complex, and you need additional services to fetch data and check application settings, guess what happens? These dependencies are passed into the factory through its constructor. You should mock these dependencies to isolate the factory from its dependencies' dependencies.  Consumers of your factory would receive a fully wired factory through their constructor; or the factory is assembled at application start-up and made available as a singleton, etc.

This is how DI works. It sounds peculiar because now you have to worry how the factory is created (and who created that object,etc, turtles all the way down) and this is a perfectly natural reaction.

That's why we have DI frameworks to assemble complex object graphs. In a well designed DI application, nothing should know how the graph was assembled. Akin to this design, nothing should know about the DI framework.

The only exception to that rule, is... (drum-roll)... a factory object!

Most DI frameworks will inject the DI container into an object if the object being resolved takes a DI in it's constructor. This greatly simplifies the factory's plumbing, and satisfies our design principles: no one knows how to construct our object except our factory and we've encapsulated knowledge of the DI container to key areas of the application that are responsible for object assembly.

Whew. Now, if you're still following along, how does this change our test? It shouldn't, at least not too much: step #1 changes slightly, where you fill the DI container with mock objects, and then construct the factory with the DI container.

As a matter of taste, some like to use auto-mocking DI containers during testing that will automatically generate mock dependencies when an item is requested. This can remove most of the set up pain.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this enlightening answer! I really learned a lot! This is why I love SO... sometimes you receive answers which will set a switch in you mind :-).

Answer (score 2):

If the `newFooBar` method had to be more complex, you could refactor out everything except for the creation of the `Foo` and the `Bar` into a package-private initialisation method.  Then write tests for the initialisation method.

```
public class GraphFactory {
     public static FooBar newFooBar() {
         Foo foo = new Foo();
         Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
         FooBar toReturn = new FooBar(foo, bar);
         initialise( toReturn );
         return toReturn;
     }

     static void initialise( FooBar toInitialise ){
          // some stuff here that you can test
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 Too bad I can only upvote this once :-). I was struggling so hard with this problem but never thought of something like this :-).

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock or stub static method calls but you can write a unit test for the factory without mocks.

But, why do you use static factory methods?. May be better to store the factory in a static variable if you want to access it in a static way.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a look into Dependecy Injection, which will allow you get rid of the factory when used properly. I recommend you this video as an introduction, it helped me a lot:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

It's an introduction to Guice, a library from google, but it will help you understand DI. Then you'll see how to replace all those 'new' with annotations, letting the library do all the work for you. Some people would recommend Sring instead, but i find Guice more friendly for beginners. I just hope this doesn't fire a Guice vs Spring discussion again :D

Comment: I use Guice regulary, and it could easily solve my problem here but sadly I can't use it in my current project. Still a good advice :-).

Comment: I'd recommend you to read recipe 14.5 Test an object Factory  from the book Junit Recipes (J.B. Rainsberger). It's pretty much what @DavidWallace said though, but formulated differently.